# I am trying to extract links in a loop using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to extract the links of a URL by using HTML Agility Pack first I am trying to enter my first URL and it is extracting the link but in the second step I want to extract the links of all extracted links in the previous step like the example below:

[image]

So here at the top I am extracting the following link and adding the extracted links to a list box. After that I want to extract the the extracted links one by one and getting their links to add them to the list box again and again.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public List<string> lstDiscoveredLinks = new List<string>();
public bool crawlSuccess;
public int count = 0;

private void extractSecondStepLinks_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
   
    foreach (string link1 in lstDiscoveredLinks)
    {
        doc = hw.Load(link1);
        var vrDocTitle = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title")?.InnerText.ToString().Trim();
        titleListBox.Items.Add(vrDocTitle);
        crawlListbox.Items.Add("Crawling (" + vrDocTitle + ") URL:");
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            // Get the value of the HREF attribute
            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
            if (!hrefValue.ToString().StartsWith("http://") && !hrefValue.ToString().StartsWith("https://"))
                continue;
            crawlListbox.Items.Add(hrefValue);
            count++;
            countWebsiteLbl.Content = "count: " + count;
            lstDiscoveredLinks.Add(hrefValue);
        }
        crawlListbox.Items.Add("*******************Finished Crawling*******************");
        crawlSuccess = true;

        //WPF ListBox Scroll to end automatically
        crawlListbox.SelectedIndex = crawlListbox.Items.Count - 1;
        crawlListbox.ScrollIntoView(crawlListbox.SelectedItem);
    }
}

private void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = hw.Load(urlTextbox.Text);
        var vrDocTitle = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title")?.InnerText.ToString().Trim();
        titleListBox.Items.Add(vrDocTitle);
        crawlListbox.Items.Add("Crawling (" + vrDocTitle + ") URL:");
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            // Get the value of the HREF attribute
            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
            if (!hrefValue.ToString().StartsWith("http://") && !hrefValue.ToString().StartsWith("https://"))
                continue;
            crawlListbox.Items.Add(hrefValue);
            count++;
            countWebsiteLbl.Content =  "count: " + count;
            lstDiscoveredLinks.Add(hrefValue.ToString());
        }
        crawlListbox.Items.Add("*******************Finished Crawling*******************");
        crawlSuccess = true;


        //WPF ListBox Scroll to end automatically
        crawlListbox.SelectedIndex = crawlListbox.Items.Count - 1;
        crawlListbox.ScrollIntoView(crawlListbox.SelectedItem);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        crawlSuccess = false;
    }
}
```

Error i am getting:

[image]

Comment: You can't append a list in a `foreach` that you're iterating over: `foreach (string link1 in lstDiscoveredLinks) { ...lstDiscoveredLinks.Add(hrefValue);}` <-- this is not allowed

Comment: then what is the solution?? any idea

Comment: Use a different list object to store your results. You can't modify a list you are iterating over in foreach loop